# Rock, Paper, Scissors with Brain.js

Tags: javascript, brain.js

I would like to learn brain.js so I decided to make a little project. I would like to make a rock, paper, scissors game where the background color would randomly change between three colors after every play.

If you'd choose that you will play one option every time a certain background color appears, the website should use brain.js and learn the pattern.

At first, the website also chooses a random option.

```
example:
background-color=blue youPlay=rock
background-color=red youPlay=paper
background-color=yellow youPlay=scissors

//when all three colors were used, the website will use a function with brain.js 

background-color=red -> website knows that you will most likely play paper based on your previous plays and it will play scissors to win
```

This is the most crucial part of the function:

```
const net = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

for(i=0; i < dataPlay.length; i++){
      net.train([{ input: [dataColor[i]], output: [dataPlay[i]] }]);
}

var output = net.run([colorVar]);
```

The background-colors are saved in dataColor[] and your plays are saved in dataPlay[]. The actual background-color is saved in colorVar.

The problem with the for loop is that the output is only based on the last item in dataColor and dataPlay. I would like to train the data from all items in dataColor and dataPlay.

Comment: You’ll have to show how you fill the dataPlay array.